# Is the domain of a finite set a finite set again without the axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don’t think that the following can be proven without $\sf AC$.

> Let $A$ be a finite set (i.e. it has a bijection with the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N} : 1\le n\le N\}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$) of Kuratowski ordered pairs (i.e. $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ for all $a,b$). Then the set of the first coordinates of ordered pairs in $A$ (i.e. the set $\{a\in\bigcup\bigl(\bigcup A\bigr) : (a,b)\in A \text{ for some b}\}$  is finite.

What do you think?

---

This is a question that I came up with, so it might lack some precision. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Oh! I think that induction (on the cardinality of $A$) might work!

Comment: AC is generally not required for theorems about finite sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed provable without choice. It's useful to rephrase it as follows:

> Suppose $X$ is finite and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective. Then $Y$ is finite.

Fix a bijection $h:X\rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $y\in Y$ let $$k(y)=\min\{h(x): f(x)=y\}.$$ Then $k$ is an injection from $Y$ to $\{1,...,n\}$. Now just "collapse" it: consider the map $$\hat{k}:Y\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}: y\mapsto \vert\{z\in Y: k(z)\le k(y)\}\vert.$$ It's not hard to show that $\hat{k}$ is a bijection between $Y$ and $\{1,...,m\}$ for some $m$.

Comment: Maybe the point of the confusion is that the argument above describes functions that are not "canonical" in the sense that they depend on an arbitrary $h$. But this of course has nothing to do with choice.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think we actually need $\sf AC$ to prove this.

We can let $A_1$ be the collection of such elements appearing to be the first coordinates of pairs in $A$. Apparently we can construct a function $f:A_1\to A$ that is one-to-one because $A$ is finite in your problem. This shows that $|A_1|\leq|A|$, so $A_1$ is also finite.